# Запрос к множественным элементам в XML в MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, запрос

Имеется конструкция вида:

```
<purchaseDoc>
    <id>...</id>
    <purchaseNumber>...</purchaseNumber>
    <lots>
        <lot>
            <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
            <lotObjectInfo>...</lotObjectInfo>
            <customerRequirements>...</customerRequirements>
            <purchaseObjects>...</purchaseObjects>
            <requirements>
                <requirement>
                    <code>...</code>
                    <name>...</name>
                    <content>...</content>
                </requirement>
                <requirement>
                    <code>...</code>
                    <name>...</name>
                    <content>...</content>
                </requirement>
                <requirement>
                    <code>...</code>
                    <name>...</name>
                    <content>...</content>
                </requirement>
            </requirements>
        </lot>
        <lot>
            <lotNumber>2</lotNumber>
            <lotObjectInfo>...</lotObjectInfo>
            <customerRequirements>...</customerRequirements>
            <purchaseObjects>...</purchaseObjects>
            <requirements>
                <requirement>
                    <code>...</code>
                    <name>...</name>
                    <content>...</content>
                </requirement>
                <requirement>
                    <code>...</code>
                    <name>...</name>
                    <content>...</content>
                </requirement>
                <requirement>
                    <code>...</code>
                    <name>...</name>
                    <content>...</content>
                </requirement>
            </requirements>
        </lot>
    </lots>
</purchaseDoc>
```

Количество вложенных `lot`, как и количество вложенных `requirement`, не известно.
Я понимаю, как получить элементы в `purchseDoc`:

```
SELECT column.value('(purchaseDoc/id) [1]', 'integer') AS 'id' FROM table
```

Понимаю, как разможить элемент `lot` с привязкой к `purchaseDoc`:

```
SELECT 
t.column.value('(purchaseDoc/id)[1]', 'integer') AS Id,
nodes.setting.value('lotNumber[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
nodes.setting.value('lotObjectInfo[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM table t
    CROSS APPLY t.column.nodes('purchaseDoc/lots/lot/.[1]') nodes(setting)
```

Получаю после данного запроса таблицу вида:

```
id | lotNumber | lotObjectInfo
```

Но не понимаю, как мне сделать так, чтобы еще дальше углубиться, чтобы разбить `requirement` с привязкой как к `lot`, так и `purchaseDoc`, то есть чтобы я получил таблицу вида:

```
id | purchaseNumber | lotNumber | code | name | content
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CROSS APPLY` делаем по самым вложенным элементам.
`lotNumber` получаем через путь к предкам.

```sql
SELECT
    #t.col.value('(purchaseDoc/id)[1]', 'integer') AS Id,
    #t.col.value('(purchaseDoc/purchaseNumber)[1]', 'integer') AS purchaseNumber,
    nodes.setting.value('../../lotNumber[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS lotNumber, 
    nodes.setting.value('code[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS code,
    nodes.setting.value('name[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS [name],
    nodes.setting.value('content[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS content
FROM #t    
    CROSS APPLY #t.col.nodes('purchaseDoc/lots/lot/requirements/requirement/.[1]') nodes(setting)
```

Comment: `#t.col.nodes('purchaseDoc/lots/lot/requirements/requirement/.[1]')` а вот этим мы разве не берем только первый лот из всех, которые могут быть?

Answer (score 1):

**Запрос для получения данных из переменной**

> ```
> declare @XML xml
>
> SELECT @XML = 
> '
> <purchaseDoc>
>     <id>1</id>
>     <purchaseNumber>100</purchaseNumber>
>     <lots>
>         <lot>
>             <lotNumber>1</lotNumber>
>             <lotObjectInfo>lotObjectInfo_1</lotObjectInfo>
>             <customerRequirements>customerRequirements_1</customerRequirements>
>             <purchaseObjects>purchaseObjects_1</purchaseObjects>
>             <requirements>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>111</code>
>                     <name>name111</name>
>                     <content>content111</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>112</code>
>                     <name>name112</name>
>                     <content>content112</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>113</code>
>                     <name>name113</name>
>                     <content>content113</content>
>                 </requirement>
>             </requirements>
>         </lot>
>         <lot>
>             <lotNumber>2</lotNumber>
>             <lotObjectInfo>lotObjectInfo_2</lotObjectInfo>
>             <customerRequirements>customerRequirements_2</customerRequirements>
>             <purchaseObjects>purchaseObjects_2</purchaseObjects>
>             <requirements>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>211</code>
>                     <name>name211</name>
>                     <content>content211</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>212</code>
>                     <name>name212</name>
>                     <content>content212</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>213</code>
>                     <name>name213</name>
>                     <content>content213</content>
>                 </requirement>
>             </requirements>
>         </lot>
>     </lots>
> </purchaseDoc>
> <purchaseDoc>
>     <id>9</id>
>     <purchaseNumber>900</purchaseNumber>
>     <lots>
>         <lot>
>             <lotNumber>91</lotNumber>
>             <lotObjectInfo>lotObjectInfo_91</lotObjectInfo>
>             <customerRequirements>customerRequirements_91</customerRequirements>
>             <purchaseObjects>purchaseObjects_91</purchaseObjects>
>             <requirements>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>9111</code>
>                     <name>name9111</name>
>                     <content>content9111</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>9112</code>
>                     <name>name9112</name>
>                     <content>content912</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>9113</code>
>                     <name>name9113</name>
>                     <content>content9113</content>
>                 </requirement>
>             </requirements>
>         </lot>
>         <lot>
>             <lotNumber>92</lotNumber>
>             <lotObjectInfo>lotObjectInfo_92</lotObjectInfo>
>             <customerRequirements>customerRequirements_92</customerRequirements>
>             <purchaseObjects>purchaseObjects_92</purchaseObjects>
>             <requirements>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>9211</code>
>                     <name>name9211</name>
>                     <content>content9211</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>9212</code>
>                     <name>name9212</name>
>                     <content>content9212</content>
>                 </requirement>
>                 <requirement>
>                     <code>9213</code>
>                     <name>name9213</name>
>                     <content>content9213</content>
>                 </requirement>
>             </requirements>
>         </lot>
>     </lots>
> </purchaseDoc>
> '
> ```
>
> ```
> SELECT 
>   y.requirement.value('(../../../.././id)[1]', 'int') as id,
>   y.requirement.value('(../.././lotNumber)[1]', 'int') as lotNumber,
>     y.requirement.value('(code)[1]', 'INT') AS code,
>     y.requirement.value('(name)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS name,
>     y.requirement.value('(content)[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS content
> FROM @xml.nodes('.') as g(r)
>    CROSS APPLY     @xml.nodes('/purchaseDoc/lots/lot/requirements/requirement') y(requirement)
> GO
> ```
>
> id | lotNumber | code | name     | content    
> :- | --------: | ---: | :------- | :----------
> 1  |         1 |  111 | name111  | content111 
> 1  |         1 |  112 | name112  | content112 
> 1  |         1 |  113 | name113  | content113 
> 1  |         2 |  211 | name211  | content211 
> 1  |         2 |  212 | name212  | content212 
> 1  |         2 |  213 | name213  | content213 
> 9  |        91 | 9111 | name9111 | content9111
> 9  |        91 | 9112 | name9112 | content912 
> 9  |        91 | 9113 | name9113 | content9113
> 9  |        92 | 9211 | name9211 | content9211
> 9  |        92 | 9212 | name9212 | content9212
> 9  |        92 | 9213 | name9213 | content9213